# set grid view's image based on a if statement

Tags: android, if-statement, gridview

So this is my grid view image and text set (or what ever you call it).

```
GridView grid;
String[] web = {
         "test",
         "test",
         "test"         
} ;
int[] imageId = {
      R.drawable.example,
      R.drawable.example,
      R.drawable.example
};
```

Now I'm trying to set it's images based on a if statement.
something like this:

```
GridView grid;
String[] web = {
            "test",
            "test",
            "test"

} ;
int[] imageId = {
    case 0:   if(blablabla == true){
                //set image 1
              }
              else{
                //set image 2
              }

    case 1:   if(blablabla == true){
                //set image 1
              }
              else{
                //set image 2
              }

    case 2:   if(blablabla == true){
                //set image 1
              }
              else{
                //set image 2
              }
    };
```

can anyone help me? i'm stuck on this for a week now.

Comment: You need to declare your own BaseAdapter and apply your logic in getView() method. Look at offical docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ArrayList and for

```
ArrayList<String> web = new ArrayList<String>;
ArrayList<Integer> imageId = new ArrayList<Integer>();


web.add("test");
web.add("test");
web.add("test");
web.add("test");

        for (int i = 0; i < web.size(); i++) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    if (blablabla == true) {
                        //set image 1
                    } else {
                        //set image 2
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (blablabla == true) {
                        //set image 1
                    } else {
                        //set image 2
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (blablabla == true) {
                        //set image 1
                    } else {
                        //set image 2
                    }
                    break;
                default:

            }

        }
```